# change ENTIRE url without redirect

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, .htaccess

i have this domain:

http://www.example.com

and when page is loaded a want to change/mask it in http://www.example2.com WITHOUT REDIRECT at the second URL

i have tried with htacces, jquery and more other solutions.

thanks

Comment: Don't think it's possible, but I'm curious about why you want to do this.

Comment: For example, to make www.bing.com show www.google.com instead?

Comment: can't do that...host in url has to resolve to your domain

Comment: This is technically not possible as it would undermine every currently implemented security stack.

Comment: If this was possible, no one would trust a website ever again.

Answer (score 1):

First off you can only control domains which you yourself host. So if you are trying to make someone go to http://www.example.com and really want them to see that page with the URL as http://facebook.com, you are out of luck.

That way is not possible and any attempt to do so would require breaking the law. However if what you want to do is just have multiple domains that you control redirect to another domain, that is possible.

For that just set a domain redirect with your registrar (ie. GoDaddy),

But for arguments sake lets say you want to move users to a new domain you own that shows the same content as the original domain where the only difference is the URL then you would have to set up the second domain with the same files as the first one or symlink the files with the first one.

But again you can't manipulate other peoples domains.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by proxying. You'd need to have control over the `example2.com` domain and setup a reverse proxy there. You can do this either in the vhost/server config or in htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example2\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [L,P]
```

Or in your vhost config:

```
ProxyPass / http://www.example.com/
```

If you don't have mod_proxy and mod_rewrite loaded, you're pretty much screwed. The best thing you can do that comes close is creating a page with an iframe that points to the other site.